# Scatter plot grouped by row for a 31 x 3 2d array

Tags: matlab

I have a 2d array and I want to scatter plot the points grouped by row so that each row has a different symbol. This is my code so far, all the points are the same symbol so I can't tell which points are part of which row.

```
a = zeros (31,3);
for k = 0:30
    y = 5*k
    dent = [1 10 10 y]
    a(k+1, [1 2 3]) = roots(dent)
end

t = 1:3


gscatter(real(a(:,t)),imag(a(:,t)));
```

Comment: Take a look at this: http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/16708

Answer (score 1):

You do not need a loop, you can exploit the [`gscatter`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/gscatter.html) options:

```
a = zeros (31,3);
for k = 0:30
    y = 5*k;
    dent = [1 10 10 y];
    a(k+1, [1 2 3]) = roots(dent);
end

group = ones(size(a));
group(:,1) = group(:,1).*0;
group(:,3) = group(:,3).*2;

gscatter(real(a(:)),imag(a(:)),group(:),'brg','xo+');
```

You need an additional vector, `group`, which contains information on which points in your data-set belong to a specific group. This variable is very versatile, see [it's documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/grouping-variables.html).
In your case, I suggest setting up a matrix that is `0` in the first column, `1` in the second and `2` in the third.
In the `gscatter` function call, reshape all your matrices into vectors using `(:)` (because `gscatter` only works with vectors.
The other two strings passed to `gscatter`:

- `'brg'`
- `'xo+'`

determine the color and shape of the symbols, respectively. Your plot then looks like this:

[image: gscatter]

**EDIT**

For those users without access to the `gscatter` function, this is how it can be done using `scatter`:

```
s = 40;
hold on
COLORS='brg';
SYMBOLS='xo+';
for t=1:size(a,2)
    scatter(real(a(:,t)),imag(a(:,t)),s,SYMBOLS(t),'MarkerEdgeColor',COLORS(t))
end
hold off
```

A few things to take note of:

- to be used in this way, `scatter` needs a symbol-size, which was set to `s = 40` in this example.
- the symbols are stored in a `string` variable so that the can be called in the loop.
- the same is true for the edge colors (face colors could also be specified, check the [`scatter` documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/scatter.html)
- when called in a loop, use `hold` to plot into the same figure (roughly speaking)

This is the output from the standard `scatter` plot:

[image: scatter]

Comment: @gsakis was my answer helpful to you?